# how can i make text visible when hover on image

Tags: html, css

why when the mouse  hover over the image the text do not  show ?
how to get the visibility of the text using visibility property in css

```css
img{
  margin-top: 110px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}



.txt{
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 440px;
  margin-right: 440px;
  visibility: hidden;
  
}

img:hover  .txt{
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container"> 
<img src="empty-boxes.svg"  style="width:520px;height:190px;">
<p class="number">404</p>
<p class="txt">When communicating via HTTP, the server is required
  .</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the CSS "`~`" selector.

```css
img {
  margin-top: 110px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.txt {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 440px;
  margin-right: 440px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

img:hover ~ .txt {
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="empty-boxes.svg" style="width:520px;height:190px;">
  <p class="number">404</p>
  <p class="txt">When communicating via HTTP, the server is required .
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the opacity of the text when hover on image

```
.txt {
  opacity: 0;
}
 img:hover~ .txt{
opacity: 1;
}
```

I recommend you to hover on the image container instead of the image itself. You can add transition on .txt to make it good looking.